# Every attempt to install SteadyFlow package returns error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

Every attempt to install the `steadyflow` package returns the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install steadyflow
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libunique-1.0-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libunique-1.0-0 steadyflow
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 184 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,373 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libunique-1.0-0 i386 1.1.6-4 [25.2 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe steadyflow i386 0.1.7-2ubuntu1 [159 kB]
Fetched 184 kB in 13s (13.9 kB/s)                                                                                                                            
Selecting previously unselected package libunique-1.0-0.
(Reading database ... 214840 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libunique-1.0-0 (from .../libunique-1.0-0_1.1.6-4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package steadyflow.
Unpacking steadyflow (from .../steadyflow_0.1.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up capiutils (1:3.12.20071127-0ubuntu11) ...
Note: running MAKEDEV to create CAPI devices in /dev...
mount: unknown filesystem type 'capifs'
invoke-rc.d: initscript capiutils, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing capiutils (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 32
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of drdsl:
 drdsl depends on capiutils; however:
  Package capiutils is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing drdsl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libunique-1.0-0 (1.1.6-4) ...
Setting up steadyflow (0.1.7-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 capiutils
 drdsl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mihirm3m@mihirm3m-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: Say, what was your question again?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please always include at least some information about how this error produced and what were you doing. Since just pasting an error code may not be very helpful for those who wants to help.

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/191235/cannot-install-or-remove-packages/191247#191247

Comment: @user61928 I don't think this question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/191235/ because it has a different error message.

Answer (score 1):

First enable all of the repositories , such as *main*, *universe* and also the *updates* and *security-updates*. Take a look at [these questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how%20to%20enable%20repository)

Try executing these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge capiutils drdsl
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Credit goes to [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1953460.html)

I'am quoting an important line from there

> If you are coming from Windows, it is important for you to know the role of a package manager. The package manager manages all installations, updates, upgrades and deinstallations. This way, you have a central place to manage your programs and their dependencies. If you stick to the official (default) repositories, you can be sure that every program you install has been tested, is virus-free (not that any Linux viruses are known, at the moment, to be in the wild), and is compatible with your system.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, you can:

1. Use **synaptic** and completely remove the broken packages then reinstall them.
2. Try the command

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```

   then try

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```