# Cannot use apt-get with the parameter --configure

Tags: command-line, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Every attempts of installation returns error code (1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191306/every-attempts-of-installation-returns-error-code-1)

```
$ sudo apt-get purge capiutils drdsl 
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done The following packages will be REMOVED:   capiutils* drdsl* 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 372 kB disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
(Reading database ... 215204 files and directories currently installed.) Removing drdsl ... 
Purging configuration files for drdsl ... 
Removing capiutils ... 
Purging configuration files for capiutils ... 
Processing triggers for man-db ... 
Processing triggers for ureadahead ... 
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot 

$ sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... 
Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 

$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get --configure --pending 
E: Command line option --configure is not understood
```

Comment: Sorry, the command will be `sudo dpkg --configure --pending`. See my [update answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/191316/61218)

Comment: Mihir Patel, Please don't ask the same question multiple times. This is the third version of it: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/191306/every-attempts-of-installation-returns-error-code-1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/191309/package-operation-failed-in-every-installing-software-or-update